# How to make this bar in android studio

Tags: android

i don't know how to make this bar in the layout in android studio?
i want the XML code for this part of the activity.

[image: bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Seekbar to achieve a similar one. Please refer this for more information: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html
This is a sample xml:

```
        <SeekBar

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:max="100" >
        </SeekBar>
```

Feel free to customize the indicators. Also, this is a good tutorial: http://abhiandroid.com/ui/seekbar